# Restricting access to root MySQL account to root UNIX account?

Tags: mysql

I was wondering if it is possible to restrict access to the MySQL root account to the UNIX root account. I guess this question can be generalized to non-root cases, so you DB gurus feel free to expand at will!

Thanks and cheers

Comment: "restrict access to the MySQL root account to the UNIX root account" > Repeated use of "to" is confusing. Can you please explain a little more

Comment: Simple answer: make the MySQL root password the same as the Unix root password. Otherwise no, any regular Unix user that knows the MySQL root password can log in as root.

Comment: Hanky Panky, I meant that user joe can access the MySQL root account if the MySQL root password is known/guessed. But as Sammitch stated, this could happen to UNIX accounts in the first place. I feel compelled to delete the question altogether! Thanks to both. Sammitch, if you put your comment as an answer I will mark it as correct.

Comment: Sammitch, in case you read this, I just learned you can lock root's password altogether via `passwd -l root`. With the use of sudoers and public-key authentication it now (apparently) makes more sense to ask this question again. More generally, it seems reasonable to designate which UNIX users can access given MySQL accounts, no?